# C - Comparing a float to an array to see if the value is in the array

Tags: arrays, c, boolean

I have a program where I need to take a value and compare it to 12 values in an array. If this value lies within the array, I need to return a true value to the main function so that it prints something if this true value is returned. I can post some of my code, but I am confused on how to return this true value.

```
 void resistor (void) // Function to input resistor and capacitor values
 {


float ra, rb, c; // Float variables for two resistor values and capacitor


while(1) // While loop to gather resistor A value

{

printf("Enter a value for Resistor Ra (kOhms):  "); // First Resistor Value
scanf("%f", &ra);

    if(ra < 1 || ra > 100) // Will repeat loop until value between 1 and 100 
is entered
    
        printf("Invalid selection, choose again.\n");
        
    else
        {
        
        break; // breaks loop when valid data is entered
        }
}

while(1) // while loop to gather Resistor B value

{

printf("Enter a value for Resistor Rb (kOhms):  "); // Second Resistor Value
scanf("%f", &rb);

    if(rb < 1 || rb > 100) // Will repeat loop until value between 1 and 100 
   is entered
    
        printf("Invalid selection, choose again.\n");
        
    else 
        {
        
        break; // breaks loop when valid data is entered
        }
}

while(1)

{

printf("\nCapacitor (uF) :  "); // Capacitor Value
scanf("%f", &c);
    
    if(c <= 0) // Repeats loop until a value greater than 0 is entered
        {
            
        printf("Invalid selection, choose again.\n");
        
        }
    else 
    {
        
        float freq = calc_freq(ra, rb, c); // call function to calculate frequency
        float duty_cycle = calc_duty_cycle(ra, rb, c); // call function to calculate duty cycle
        
        
        
        printf("\nFrequency is: %.2f kHz\n", freq); // print frequency
        printf("Duty cycle is: %.2f percent\n\n", duty_cycle * 100); // print duty cycle
        checkstdval(ra, rb);
            if{
            raa = 1;
            printf("Resistor A is not")
            }
        break;
        

    }
    
    
         
 }

 main(); // Returns to beginning of program following calculations

 }
 bool checkstdval (float ra, float rb)
 {
int i; // variable used to initilize array
bool raa, rbb;

// Array of standard values for resistors
int stdv[12] = {10, 12, 15, 18, 22, 27, 33, 39, 47, 56, 68, 82}; 

while(1)
{

    while (ra <10)
    ra *= 10;
    
    while (ra >= 100)
    ra /= 10;
    
    i = 0;
    for(i<12; i++ ;)
        if ((ra - stdv[i]) < 0.01)
        
            return raa = 1;
        
        else
        {
        return raa = 0;
        break;
        }   
}
        
        


while(1)
{

    while (rb <10)
    rb *= 10;
    while (rb >= 100)
    rb /= 10;
    
    i = 0;
    for(i<12; i++ ;)
        if ((rb - stdv[i]) < 0.01)
        
            return rbb = 1;
        
        else
        {
            return rbb = 0;
            break;
        }
}
        
 }
```

Comment: You need to get the absolute value of `ra - stdv[i]`.

Comment: It's bad practice to call `main`

Comment: What is the purpose of the `break` after a `return` statement? And when `raa` is a local variable, `return raa=1` is totally equal to `return 1`. Inside of your `for` loops, both branches of your `if` statement calls `return`, so the loop will only run once. Oh and calling `main()` doesn't *return* to main, it calls main, which @stark correctly states is bad practice. Are you sure you understand how program flow works in a c-program?

Comment: do NOT call `main()` from within the program.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: (the compiler does not care) 1) please use meaningful variable names.  2) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'` Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf("%f", &ra);`  There are many ways that the user can cause this statement to fail.  Therefore, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful 'input conversion specifier' matches ( or EOF ).  In the current statement, any value returned, other than 1, indicates an error occurred

Comment: OT:  regarding: ` while (ra <10)
    ra *= 10;
    
    while (ra >= 100)
    ra /= 10;`   the literals 10, 100 are integers.  Much better to use floats.  Suggest:   `while (ra <10.0f)
    ra *= 10.0f;
    
    while (ra >= 100.0f)
    ra /= 10.0f;`

Comment: regarding: `i = 0;
    for(i<12; i++ ;)`  This is nonsense.  Suggest: `for( int i = 0; i<12; i++ )`

Comment: regarding: `int stdv[12] = {10, 12, 15, 18, 22, 27, 33, 39, 47, 56, 68, 82};` 1) These values are being compared to floats, 2) the compiler can easily calculate the number of entries in the array.   so the line should be: `float stdv[] = { 10.0f, 12.0f, 15.0f, 18.0f, 22.0f, 27.0f, 33.0f, 39.0f, 47.0f, 56.0f, 68.0f, 82.0f };`

Comment: the posted code contains the 'magic' number 12.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  Suggest `sizeof( stdv ) / sizeof( stdv[0] )`  which will always calculate the number of entries in the array, regardless of the number of entries in the array

Answer (score -2):

Comparing floats is a topic in itself. A solution is in **https://www.embeddeduse.com/2019/08/26/qt-compare-two-floats/** where the Qt function `qFuzzyCompare` is used and comparing of floats is analyzed deeper